# Web Essentials is adding .js.map to the project when saving a TypeScript file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I only want to include the .ts and .js files in the .csproj. The format currently used is:

```
<Content Include="Scripts\FooterItems\EnableAccount.js">
  <DependentUpon>EnableAccount.ts</DependentUpon>
</Content>
<TypeScript Include="Scripts\FooterItems\EnableAccount.ts" />
```

(I have a custom build target file that targets TypeScript elements during build).

I've installed Web Essentials, which has some features that help with TypeScript development, particularly the "Compile TS to JS on save". However, it's generating both the .js and the .js.map source map file. It also adds the .js.map file to the .csproj, which is the annoying bit. Note that this is with the "Generate Source Map" setting set to False.

Anyone else spotted this, and has run into a similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our custom build targets seem to have exposed a bug in Web Essentials 2012 TypeScript features.

Web Essentials compiled the .ts to .js, but we already had a .js.map generated by the curtom build targets as well. Web Essentials ended up including the .js.map in the csproj and TFS source control.

Removing the .js.map files and making sure we don't generate them in our build targets fixed the issue.